# How can I listen to the output of a console command and react to it outside of the listener?

Tags: c#

I am listening to the output of a console command that I am executing as such:

```
Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
info.RedirectStandardError = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
    delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received data: " + e.Data);
        if (e.Data == "FAIL")
        {
            // I need to react to this outside the delegate,
            // e.g. stop the process and return <false>.
        }
    }

);

p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();

using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
{
    if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
    {
        sw.WriteLine("echo Hello World 1");
        sw.WriteLine("echo FAIL");
        sw.WriteLine("echo Hello World 2");
        sw.WriteLine("echo Hello World 3");
        sw.WriteLine("exit");
    }
}

p.BeginOutputReadLine();
p.WaitForExit();
```

This works as expected, but here's what I don't know how to do: When the process produces the "FAIL" line into its output, I would like to react to this outside of the delegate, i.e. in the method that spawned the process. How can I do that? It seems to me that the only context that I have while in the delegate is the sender (which is the process) and the data produced.

I tried to have the delegate throw an exception and catch that in a try-catch block around the `p.Start()` and all the other code, but the exception doesn't get caught.

Comment: @Frunk This is not Java, so `==` is OK too.

Comment: The two processes are communicating asynchronously, so reacting to the `FAIL` message out of band may happen too late. Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dzCgga3P) with your modified program that uses a little hacking around with `AutoResetEvent` to send signals from the reader to the writer, but it has some serious race conditions, so you should not use it in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to react to the `FAIL` line immediately if you're trying to wait and then return a value. What you should do instead is have your delegate set a flag. You can then check that flag after your `p.WaitForExit` call and return the appropriate value:

```
var hasFailed = false;

// Set up process

p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
    delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == "FAIL") hasFailed = true;
    }
);

// Start Process

p.WaitForExit();

if(hasFailed)
{
    // Handle the fact that the process failed and return appropriately.
}

// Otherwise the process succeeded and we can return normally.
```